# AWS Instance Suddenly Unavailable in Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ip

I am very new AWS and sys admin so bear with me...

I noticed my website was suddenly down today and have been working to sniff out the issue.  Here is what I have checked:

It was working fine until today, so it isn't a DNS issue but I double checked.

SSH works fine

Rebooted the instance - no change

Security Group Settings fine - port 80 and 443 open (site is SSL secured)

Tried adding ALL ICMP 0.0.0.0/0 for testing - pinging started working, still no browser response

Tried various iptable commands noted in other similar posts (not that I understand them) to no effect

I am at a loss and appreciate any assistance with locating and correcting the issue.

Here are the instance details:

Public DNS: ec2-54-213-52-95.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Public IP: 54.213.52.95

Instance ID: i-f331b5fe

Comment: Off-topic here. Try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server issues and serverfault.com has been removed from the 'belongs on another site' migration list.

Comment: Sorry for the misplaced question! Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon restarted all of their servers today for a few hours